# LayoutResult more one page in Itext7

Tags: itext, itext7

i ask this: [Remove the first and last lines properties in the paper Itext7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350909/remove-the-first-and-last-lines-properties-in-the-paper-itext7/56356879#56356879)

and if i do it:

```
 PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(dest);


    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    Div div = new Div();
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A5);
    doc.setMargins(0,0,0,36);

    for (int i = 0; i <50 ; i++) {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        String s= "hello "+i;
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        for (int j = 0; j <s.length() ; j++) {


            p.add("HELLO " +I);


        }


  LayoutResult result = div.createRendererSubTree().setParent(doc.getRenderer()).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0,PageSize.A5)));


List<IRenderer> childRendererParagraph = result.getSplitRenderer().getChildRenderers();
```

childRendererParagraph contain Paragraphs only from first page.And i don't know how many pages well be in pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the answer to your previous question,

> split renderer represent the part of the content which iText can place on the area, overflow - the content which overflows.

So if you want to layout the rest of the content, you can perform the same operation (`layout`) on your `overflowRenderer`.

The code is as follows:

```
    LayoutResult firstPageResult = div.createRendererSubTree().setParent(doc.getRenderer()).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, PageSize.A5)));
    LayoutResult secondPageResult  = firstPageResult.getOverflowRenderer().layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, PageSize.A5)));
```

Once the content has been fully placed, the overflowRenderer will be null.

Comment: Once the content has been fully placed, the overflowRenderer will be null.

Comment: but it is problem. I need to get full content.

Comment: Could you explain once more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i read text from file, and I set TextTise to some word(random).And if text with textRise on the first or the last line i remove property textrise.

Comment: @heavywar *"Once the content has been fully placed, the overflowRenderer will be null."* - **"but it is problem. I need to get full content."** - then simply do it again and again in a loop until the `OverflowRenderer` is `null`, i.e. until the full content has been processed.

Comment: @mkl if i set margin top, LayoutResult not working properly,  childRenderers is wrong. Two page starts with "hello 22"   https://ibb.co/sVvhC4C and in pdf two page starts with "hello 20", pdf :https://ibb.co/WtWcJMb

Comment: The emulation of layout works exactly the same as real layout (Document#add). Perhaphs you don't consider some properties during emulation.

Comment: On which element do you set the top margin?

Comment: Only to Document

Comment: But you don't use any `Document` instance during emulation. So how do you expect iText to process it? :)

Why don't you set margin on the `Div` instance which you use to emulate layout?

Comment: i tried. i do it:  div.setMargins(0,0,36,36); doc.setMargins(0,0,36,36); and it doesn't work. https://ibb.co/3WrRw61 . PDF :https://ibb.co/71Q5c19

Answer (score 0):

pdf.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(595, 14400));
Resize the page to display all content on one page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).